# Prevent an image to be dropped on top of another one

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have a `div` which holds a few images and two other `divs` that are initially empty. I want to be able to drag and drop images between the 3 divs, but without overwriting eachother.

I have everything working, except the overwriting part: if you drop an image in an area of the div that is not populated, it will simply add it at the end.
However if you drop the image on top of another image, it will only show the first one that has been dropped (the second one dissapears).

Is it possible to prevent images from being dropped on top of other images and instead just append them to the div?

Answer (score 0):

There is a object property you can set for this. You apply the rules of what is able to be dropped where, and what is not.You can set a class for this rule, and I think combined with "tolerance" setting, will do what you need.

If this doesnt fit your needs, then you might want to just you sortable for this task.